# Delphi XE7/XE8 - Refresh no banco de dados (atualização em tempo real)

Tags: mysql, delphi, firebird, firedac

Tenho dois sistemas interligados, uma salva um registro no banco de dados e outro lê o registro salvo, atualmente uso um timer para dar um refresh no banco no sistema que lê, assim ele pega a cada 5 segundos o que foi salvo pelo outro, mas acredito não ser a melhor forma. O Delphi já tem alguma funcionalidade que permita esse tipo de leitura no banco de forma "persistente" ou tem tempo real?

Banco é MySql ou Firebird (com firedac)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em geral, pode-se usar os *eventos/notificações* do banco de dados, o termo exato e a implementação depende do DBMS, pois cada um usa um [*mecanismo*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29#DBMS_Alert_Mechanisms) diferente. O Firebird por exemplo, implementa isto usando a instrução [`POST_EVENT`](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=psql&topic=102), o PostgreSQL usa [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html), etc.

Com o FireDAC, é possível obter os alertas usando o componente [`TFDEventAlerter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDEventAlerter), a página [**Database Alerts (FireDAC)**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Database_Alerts_%28FireDAC%29#See_Also) da *Embarcadero* menciona:

> O alerta DBMS refere-se a uma notificação do banco de dados ou alerta
>   enviado por um gatilho de banco de dados ou *stored procedure*
>   com o objetivo de notificar um cliente de banco de dados sobre alguns
>   eventos no lado do banco de dados.
>
> Um alerta é identificado pelo nome e pode incluir argumentos
>   adicionais. Os clientes estão registrando com alertas. Vários clientes
>   podem se registrar com um único alerta, e um cliente pode se registrar
>   com vários alertas. Quando um alerta é sinalizado em um banco de
>   dados, todos os clientes registados serão notificados sobre isso.
>   Quando um alerta não é mais usado, a aplicação cancela o registro para
>   esse alerta.

Comment: Perfeito, é isso mesmo!